# SQL Server to Entity Framework data type mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to know the equivalent SQL Server data types for EF. I found 2 similar online references, but their definitions appear inconsistent. Which reference should I refer to if I'm using Entity Framework?

1) **Data Type Mappings in ADO.NET**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

2) **SQL Server Data Types in the .NET Framework**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Comment: What kind of EF? Database-First, Code-First? Code-First to an existing DB? What do you want to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which of the two links above would you refer to for Code-First? I need to know the equivalent SQL Server data types for EF. But the Microsoft provides 2 different online references... which one is right?

Comment: You could do as Julie has done here http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/sql-server-2008-data-types-and-entity-framework-4/ and create an entity with every data type and see how it works out.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of those.

Entity Framework maps SQL Server data types to **conceptual model types ("Edm types")**. The mapping can be found here:

- [SqlClient for Entity FrameworkTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344(v=vs.110).aspx)

Edm types in turn translate to .NET types in a straightforward way (Boolean -> Boolean, Int32 -> Int32, Binary -> Byte array, etc.) and can be found in the reference code:

- [Source for `PrimitiveType.ClrEquivalentType`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Metadata/Edm/PrimitiveType.cs,b70fe00c02dfc973)